# DevExpress ASPxGridLookup set selected value when the key field name has multiple fields

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress ASPxGridLookup with a KeyFieldName with multiple fields such as "field1;field2;field3".  I am having trouble trying to set the selected value.

I have another one that just has one field for the key.  So, it works on the server side when I do something like the following:
lkMyControl.DataBind();
lkMyControl.Text = "SelectedKey";

But when I try to do something similar with the control with multiple keys, the text just stays blank.  I have tried setting the Text property using the text in the same format as would be displayed on the control.  But it just stays blank.  I also tried lkMyControlWithMultipleKeyFields.GridView.Selection.SelectRowByKey("1;2;3").  But I just get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that what I had to do was to create a new field "ID" is a string in the view class that is used by the ASPxGridLookup.  When setting the QueryableSource, I concatenated the key fields together, separated by a pipe character.

```
protected void dsSelecting(object sender, DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)    
{    
    e.KeyExpression = "ID"
    e.QueryableSource = _Model.MyTable.Select(x => new MyView()
        {
            ID = x.KeyField1 + "|" + x.KeyField2 + "|" + x.KeyField3,
            OtherField = x.OtherField
        });
}
```

**Do not use String.Format when setting the ID value since entity does not know how to interpret that into sql.**

When setting the value of the control, I did the following

```
lkMyControl.DataBind();
lkMyControl.Value = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", data.KeyField1, data.KeyField2, data.KeyField3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ASPxGridLookup.GridView.Selection.SelectRowByKey** method is intended for setting selected value**S** in a multiple selection mode (**SelectionMode = Multiple**). Check the [How to use ASPxGridLookup in multiple selection mode as the ASPxGridView editor](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-use-aspxgridlookup-in-multiple-selection-mode-as-the-aspxgridview-editor-e3981/blob/15.1.3%2B/CS/WebSite/Default.aspx.cs#L37) example.

However, if the (SelectionMode = Single), but your have a composite KeyFieldName, set a value in the same manner via the ASPxGridLookup.Text property:

```
//kMyControlWithMultipleKeyFields.GridView.Selection.SelectRowByKey("1;2;3").
kMyControlWithMultipleKeyFields.Text = "1;2;3";
```

Or, ever better set the ASPxGridLookup.Value property (like [here](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-use-two-way-data-bound-aspxgridlookup-in-edit-form-of-aspxgridview-to-edit-data-e2979/blob/15.1.3%2B/CS/WebSite/Default.aspx#L30)), because ASPxGridLookup.Text requires matching the ASPxGridLookup.TextFormatString setting.